# how to count more than 1 values

Tags: php, arrays, count

```
$array = array(array('car1', 'car2'), 
array('car1', 'car2', 'car3'),
array('car1', 'car2', 'car3'));
```

I want a result:
[car1][car2] = 3 
[car1][car2][car3] = 2

Comment: You forgot to include your code so far and the output/errors you're getting.

Comment: have a look at the [docs](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php#refsect1-function.array-count-values-examples), 
though you will have to modify it to work with multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array, then iterate the array again and push the index into the array, but increment the values in case they existed previously.

```
$count_values = array();
foreach ($array as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $b) {
        $count_values[$b]++;
    }
}
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/H5fQgN)

And the [documentation for array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php#50661) has this answer within it, which as mentioned in the comments above. Always check documentation first.

Answer (score 0):

Code below is in php doc;

```
<?php

$ar1[] = array("red","green","yellow","blue");
$ar1[] = array("green","yellow","brown","red","white","yellow");
$ar1[] = array("red","green","brown","blue","black","yellow");
#$ar1= array("red","green","brown","blue","black","red","green"); // Possible with one     or multiple Array

$res = array_icount_values ($ar1);
print_r($res);

function array_icount_values($arr,$lower=true) {
     $arr2=array();
     if(!is_array($arr['0'])){$arr=array($arr);}
     foreach($arr as $k=> $v){
      foreach($v as $v2){
       if($lower==true) {$v2=strtolower($v2);}
       if(!isset($arr2[$v2])){
          $arr2[$v2]=1;
       }else{
          $arr2[$v2]++;
       }
     }
    }
    return $arr2;
 }
/*
Will print:
Array
(
    [red] => 3
    [green] => 3
    [yellow] => 4
    [blue] => 2
    [brown] => 2
    [white] => 1
    [black] => 1
)
*/
?>
```

link:  https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.array-count-values.php#95713